# How can I store and retrieve a file as a COMPRESSED binary blob in an SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've seen a lot of sample code on the internet showing how to compress and decompress *files* on the filesystem, and a lot of sample code on how to store *regular* files in an SQL Server database, but never at the same time. Here's the code I have so far. (I'm using Entity Framework in VB.NET, but that's beside the point. I hope.)

```
Private Sub ButtonStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStore.Click

    Dim db As New Storage
    Dim bld = db.Builds.Find(1)
    Dim ecfg_file = New FileStream("D:\Temp\X1_450_1750_60207003.ecfg", FileMode.Open)
    Dim sr = New StreamReader(ecfg_file)
    Dim contents = sr.ReadToEnd

    Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
    Dim comp_stream = New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress)
    Dim sw = New StreamWriter(comp_stream)
    sw.Write(contents)
    sw.Flush()
    comp_stream.Flush()
    ms.Flush()

    bld.EcfgFile = ms.ToArray()

    db.SaveChanges()
    db.Dispose()
    ecfg_file.Close()
    comp_stream.Close()
    ms.Close()

End Sub


Private Sub ButtonExtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExtract.Click

    Dim db As New Storage
    Dim bld = db.Builds.Find(1)
    Dim ecfg_file = New FileStream("D:\Temp\asdf.ecfg", FileMode.Create)

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    ms.Write(bld.EcfgFile.ToArray, 0, bld.EcfgFile.Length)
    ms.Position = 0
    Dim decompression_stream = New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, True)
    Dim sr = New StreamReader(decompression_stream)
    Dim asdf = sr.ReadToEnd
    Dim sw = New StreamWriter(ecfg_file)
    sw.Write(asdf)

    ecfg_file.Close()
    decompression_stream.Close()
    ms.Close()

End Sub
```

This is really close. The problem is that, on extraction, the file overwrites part of itself, or stops short. The original file is 18,613 KB, and the stored and extracted on is 18,446 KB. I don't even know if the problem is occurring during the storing or extracting process.

As you can see, I'm trying to `.Flush` and `.Close()` everything to make sure that everything is done properly. (Yes, I could try `Using`, but I don't like all the indentations it would wind up making.)

Comment: I would try creating a new temp file in `Store_Click` to verify that the read/compress steps are correct.  BTW, `Using` is not just a stylistic thing - you have lots of disposable objects there not being disposed - which `Using` would take care of for you.  CA would tell you all about it.

Comment: "I don't like all the indentations it would wind up making" -> the indentations make your code far easier to read in the future.  I would strongly recommend you reconsider since the advantages of using `USING` blocks in your code far outweigh your preference of not having the code indented.

Comment: Also, what is your intention?  Are you attempting to compress the files to save space in SQL Server?  If so, you could use `PAGE COMPRESSION` in the table definition and get automatic, transparent compression.

Comment: "CA would tell you about it." What's "CA"?

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to save about 90% of my space requirements, as these are XML files that will compress well. `PAGE COMPRESSION` is new to me, but this has to (eventually) run in Azure, and I see that it's not supported there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plutonix was right about cleanup of objects using `Using` blocks, and Max Vernon was probably right about the readability of the code.

This works:

```
Private Sub ButtonStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStore.Click

    Dim contents As String

    Using ecfg_file = New FileStream("C:\Temp\X1_450_1750_60207003.ecfg", FileMode.Open)
        Using sr = New StreamReader(ecfg_file)
            contents = sr.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Using

    Using ms = New MemoryStream()
        Using comp_stream = New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress)
            Using sw = New StreamWriter(comp_stream)
                sw.Write(contents)
            End Using
        End Using
        Using db As New Storage
            Dim bld = db.Builds.First
            bld.EcfgFile = ms.ToArray()
            db.SaveChanges()
        End Using
    End Using

    Debug.Print("Done")

End Sub


Private Sub ButtonExtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExtract.Click

    Dim contents As String

    Using db As New Storage
        Dim bld = db.Builds.First
        Using ms = New MemoryStream()
            ms.Write(bld.EcfgFile.ToArray, 0, bld.EcfgFile.Length)
            ms.Position = 0
            Using decompression_stream = New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, True)
                Using sr = New StreamReader(decompression_stream)
                    contents = sr.ReadToEnd
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Using ecfg_file = New FileStream("C:\Temp\asdf.ecfg", FileMode.Create)
        Using sw = New StreamWriter(ecfg_file)
            sw.Write(contents)
        End Using
    End Using

    Debug.Print("Done")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

You may find CLR runtime functions, such as [DeflateStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (sample implementation in [this article](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2015/04/07/compressing-lob-xml-data-in-the-database/)) and [GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) useful.

Long answer:

I assume you're storing your files in your database in a varbinary(max) column, and from what I gather from [Kornelis](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2013/01/31/why-does-sql-server-not-compress-data-on-lob-pages.aspx), SQL Server unfortunately does not compress large object (LOB) data the way you want it to with page compression (or row compression, or columnstore indexes for that matter, which I assume extends to columnstore_archive). The author essentially indicates that this is because data that spans multiple pages (as LOB data naturally would) wouldn't benefit from this type of compression.

I'm searching for a similar solution, and so far I'm leaning towards using CLR functions for compression, essentially compressing the data before writing it to the table and de-compressing after reading it back out. This comes with consequences though as I understand it, like not being able to use certain search features on the compressed data and--according to [Henderson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/04/25/411852.aspx)--not being able to do asynchronous reads/writes to it anymore.

Comment: I had forgotten about this whole question. Even though the USING blocks caused the code to work correctly, and I got the behavior I was going for, I gave up on storing files in the database, and started using Azure blob storage. It's more of a pain to keep the "filesystem" and the DB in sync, but blob storage space is much cheaper than DB table space. Your comments on the compression "boundaries" is intriguing, as I had no way to effectively gauge if my method was actually saving me space on disk. Maybe not.